# Regex in JavaScript for validating decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, numbers, decimal

I want a regex in JavaScript for validating decimal numbers.

It should allow only up to two decimal places. For example, it should allow `10.89` but not `10.899`.

It should also allow only one period (`.`). For example, it should allow `10.89` but not `10.8.9`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/468655/55209

Comment: duplicate : stackoverflow.com/q/468655/55209

Answer (score 54):

Try the following expression: `^\d+\.\d{0,2}$` If you want the decimal places to be optional, you can use the following: `^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$`

**EDIT:** To test a string match in Javascript use the following snippet:

```
var regexp = /^\d+\.\d{0,2}$/;

// returns true
regexp.test('10.5')
```

Comment: @micha, sorry fixed the typo in my first regexp

Comment: Use var regexp = /^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$/; if you want to have a optional commaseparator.

Answer (score 54):

### Positive decimals only

```
/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

### Negative or positive decimals

```
/^-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

---

### Demo

```js
var regexp = /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/;

console.log("POSITIVE ONLY");
console.log("'.74' returns " + regexp.test('.74'));
console.log("'7' returns " + regexp.test('7'));
console.log("'-4' returns " + regexp.test('-4'));
console.log("'10.5' returns " + regexp.test('10.5'));
console.log("'115.25' returns " + regexp.test('115.25'));
console.log("'-120.56' returns " + regexp.test('-120.56'));
console.log("'1535.803' returns " + regexp.test('1535.803'));
console.log("'153.14.5' returns " + regexp.test('153.14.5'));
console.log("'415351108140' returns " + regexp.test('415351108140'));
console.log("'415351108140.55' returns " + regexp.test('415351108140.55'));
console.log("'415351108140.556' returns " + regexp.test('415351108140.556'));

regexp = /^-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/;

console.log("\n");
console.log("POSITIVE OR NEGATIVE");
console.log("'.74' returns " + regexp.test('.74'));
console.log("'7' returns " + regexp.test('7'));
console.log("'-4' returns " + regexp.test('-4'));
console.log("'10.5' returns " + regexp.test('10.5'));
console.log("'115.25' returns " + regexp.test('115.25'));
console.log("'-120.56' returns " + regexp.test('-120.56'));
console.log("...");
```

---

### Explanation

1. `/ /` : the beginning and end of the expression
2. `^` : whatever follows should be at the beginning of the string you're testing
3. `\d+` : there should be at least one digit
4. `( )?` : this part is optional
5. `\.` : here goes a dot
6. `\d{1,2}` : there should be between one and two digits here
7. `$` : whatever precedes this should be at the end of the string you're testing

If you also want to support negative decimals, you just need to add `-?` right after the `^`, which means that an optional minus sign is allowed there as well.

---

### Tip

You can use [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) or [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for testing regular expressions directly in the browser!

Comment: How would I extend this to accept negative numbers as well?

Comment: @KylianMbappe : I just updated my answer to add support for negative decimals

Comment: Here is a better solution for me `/^\d{0,13}(\.\d{1,2}0*)?$/.test(yourNumber)`  to allow `10.1200` that you can remove using `Number(yourNumber.toFixed(2))` but only when the condition is correct !

Answer (score 43):

```
^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

will allow:

1. `244`
2. `10.89`
3. `9.5`

will disallow:

1. `10.895`
2. `10.`
3. `10.8.9`

Comment: @ShardaprasadSoni see my post for an example

Comment: If I type 0000.100 which will be invalid decimal what the regExp should be?

Answer (score 4):

Numbers with at most 2 decimal places:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

This should work fine. Please try out :)

Comment: How can I set the max decimals with a variable? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Please see my project of the cross-browser filter of value of the text input element on your web page using JavaScript language: [Input Key Filter](https://github.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter) . You can filter the value as an integer number, a float number, or write a custom filter, such as a phone number filter. See an example of custom filter of input of an float number with decimal pointer and limitation to 2 digit after decimal pointer:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Input Key Filter Test</title>
 <meta name="author" content="Andrej Hristoliubov anhr@mail.ru">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 
 <!-- For compatibility of IE browser with audio element in the beep() function.
 https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible -->
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/InputKeyFilter.css" type="text/css">  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/Common.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/InputKeyFilter.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Float field</h1>
<input id="Float" 
 onchange="javascript: onChangeFloat(this)"
 onblur="inputKeyFilter.isNaN(parseFloat(this.value), this);"
/>
<script>
 function CreateFloatFilterCustom(elementID, onChange, onblur){
  try{
   inputKeyFilter.Create(elementID
    , onChange
    , function(elementInput, value){//customFilter
     if(value.match(/^(-?\d*)((\.(\d{0,2})?)?)$/i) == null){
      inputKeyFilter.TextAdd(isRussian() ?
        "Допустимый формат: -[0...9].[0...9] или -[0...9]e-[0...9]. Например: -12.34 1234"
        : "Acceptable formats: -[0...9].[0...9] or -[0...9]e-[0...9]. Examples: -12.34 1234"
       , elementInput);
      return false;
     }
     return true;
    }
    , onblur
   )
  } catch(e) {
   consoleError("Create float filter failed. " + e);
  }
 }
 
 CreateFloatFilterCustom("Float");
 
 function onChangeFloat(input){
  inputKeyFilter.RemoveMyTooltip();
  var elementNewFloat = document.getElementById("NewFloat");
  var float = parseFloat(input.value);
  if(inputKeyFilter.isNaN(float, input)){
   elementNewFloat.innerHTML = "";
   return;
  }
  elementNewFloat.innerHTML = float;
 }
</script>
 New float: <span id="NewFloat"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Also see my page [example of the input key filter](https://anhr.github.io/InputKeyFilter/)

Comment: Can we restrict before decimal to be only 6 digits ?

Comment: replace from /^(-?\d*)((\.(\d{0,2})?)?)$/i to /^(-?\d{0,6})((\.(\d*)?)?)$/i

Answer (score 4):

I found that I could use

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

for more than two decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

Try a regular expression like this:

```
(?=[^\0])(?=^([0-9]+){0,1}(\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}$)
```

**Allowed:**
1,
10.8,
10.89,
.89,
0.89,
1000

**Not Allowed:**
20. ,
50.89.9,
12.999,
.,
Null character
Note this works for positive numbers

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for decimal numbers validation, for completeness' sake, I'd use a regex that doesn't allow strings like 06.05.

```
^((0(\.\d{1,2})?)|([1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?))$
```

Slightly more complicated, but returns false in that case.

Edit:

```
^-?((0(\.\d{1,2})?)|([1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?))$
```

if you want negative numbers as well.

Comment: This actually does not handle decimals in range [0, 1)

Comment: It does, test here https://regex101.com/. Particularly, this first half does (0(\.\d{1,2})?). Or at least it does up to 2 decimal places like OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

as compared from the answer gven by mic...
it doesnt validate anything in some of the platforms which i work upon...
to be precise it doesnt actually work out in Dream Viewer..

hereby..
i re-write it again..which will work on any platform..
**"^[0-9]+(.[0-9]{1,2})?$"..**
thnkss..

Answer (score 0):

```
 function CheckValidAmount() {
        var amounttext = document.getElementById('txtRemittanceNumber').value;            
        if (!(/^[-+]?\d*\.?\d*$/.test(amounttext))){
            alert('Please enter only numbers into amount textbox.')
            document.getElementById('txtRemittanceNumber').value = "10.00";
        }
    }
```

This is the function which will take decimal number with any number of decimal places and without any decimal places.

Thanks ... :)

Comment: Can you post the code as text rather than an image?

Comment: for what did you used var amount = parseFloat(amounttext); if later you are using test(amounttext) and amount is not used anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The schema for passing the value in as a string. The regex will validate a string of at least one digit, possibly followed by a period and exactly two digits:

```
{
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]{2})?$"
}
```

The schema below is equivalent, except that it also allows empty strings:

```
{
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^$|^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]{2})?$"
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Does this work?

```
[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}
```

Comment: `.` stands for any character | `[0-9]` is the same as `\d`