# Decimal validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, decimal, dom-events

I use the following Script for Decimal validate. I need to enter only numbers and dot symbol like 123.00 only. The following function does not support letters that fine, but it does not allow to **enter dot(.)** symbol also? How to enter dot symbol using this function?

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
         else
         return true;
      }
```

Comment: it will be useful checkout..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023845/regex-in-javascript-for-validating-decimal-number

Answer (score 1):

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;

          return true;
       }
```

Comment: It was work fine. but its allow 123.23.45..... more than one dot.How to restrict to allow only one dot

Comment: Give id to input box, while validation, get the value of the textbox and split with ".", if array greater than 2, then return

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions, its a more elegant method.

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode.match('/^[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$/'))
            return false;
         else
         return true;
      }
```

Comment: It gives the following error Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library? match() is a jQuery method.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateFloatKeyPress2(valor, presicion, event) {
        var keyCode = (document.all) ? event.keyCode : event.which;
        if (keyCode == 8) {
            return true;
        }            
        if (keyCode == 46 && valor.value.indexOf(".") >= 0) {               
            return false;
        }
        //Enable Only float values
        if ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode == 46)) {

            if (reverse(valor.value).indexOf(".") > (presicion - 1)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

function reverse(s) {
        var o = '';
        for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            o += s[i];
        return o;
    }
```

Comment: Accepts decimal numbers, for IE and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

//Validating Numeric Fields

```
function validate(x) {
    var decimal = /^[1-9][\.\d]*(,\d+)?$/;
    if (x.match(decimal)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also you can check parseFloat method and that returns NaN.

Answer (score 0):

check thorugh isNaN() method

var a =3.00003

isNaN(a) will return false

var b ='3.0.0'
isNaN(b) will return true

i think this method will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
      function checkDecimal(num){   

        var chkDecimal=  /^\d+\.\d{0,2}$/;
        return  chkDecimal.test(num);

      }

      alert(checkDecimal(0.2)) 
      alert(checkDecimal(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution for your problem is

```
function isNumberKey(e)
    {
        var code = (code ? code : e.which);           
        if (code != 46 && code > 31 && (code < 48 || code > 57))
            return false;
            //if it is (.)
        else if (code == 46) {
             var Value = this.value;
            //if value already contains (.) character
            if (Value.indexOf('.') != -1) {
                var splt = Value.split('.');
                //if there is already(.) char then return false
                if (splt.length >= 2)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function IsNumeric(e) {
        var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        var ret = ((keyCode == 46 || keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
        return ret;
}
```