# How to validate decimal positions with Parsley or HTML5?

Tags: html, parsley.js

How can I validate an input to have an exact amount of decimals?
For instance, if I want to validate a number to have 2 decimals then I want to validate as follow:

- 2.888 -> fails
- 2.8 -> fails
- 2 -> fails
- 2.88 -> validates

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the `data-parsley-pattern` attribute, and use a regular expression to match number to 2 decimal places:

```
data-parsley-pattern="^[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}$"
```

Also, remember to add a `required` attribute to your tag.

Comment: What about 'optional' decimal places? I mean, if I enter "2.00" is valid and "2" is valid too. How the regex should be in this case? Thank you!

Comment: I found it! ^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$

Comment: @brugnner I see a couple issues with that regex. For one, you probably want to be using [0-9], not [1-9]. This pattern would work much better: [0-9]*(\.?[0-9]{2}$)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the data-parsley-pattern attribute, and use a regular expression to match numbers to 2 decimal places or zero.

```
^[0-9]{1,}\.?[0-9]{0,2}$
```

for example:

- If the value is 1.00 then it will valid
- If the value is 123.00 then it will valid
- If the value is .00 then it will not valid
- If the value is 1.000 then it will not valid

Answer (score 0):

[From java script answer for decimal validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023845/regex-in-javascript-for-validating-decimal-numbers/31737906)

data-parsley-pattern="^\d+(.\d{1,2})?$"

also, please check if input type="text"