# Condition checking inside antd form of React + Validation needed

Tags: reactjs, redux, antd

This is my `FormItem`

```
<FormItem label="Rate">
    {getFieldDecorator('ORSalesAndPurchaseSalesPrice', {
        initialValue: "",                   
    })(
        <Input placeholder="Rate(0.00)"/>
    )}
</FormItem>
```

The condition I need is

```
if(value.ItemTpeId ==1)
  <Input placeholder="Rate(0.00)"/>
else
  <Input placeholder="Rate(%)"/>
```

How should I apply this logic for placeholder  inside `FormItem`?
I also need validation to this field so that only numbers and a decimal point is allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ternary operator.

```
<Input placeholder={value.ItemTpeId === 1 ? "Rate(0.00)" : "Rate(%)"}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's take Rate in one variable

```
const rate = (value.ItemTpeId===1) ? "Rate(0.00)" : "Rate(%)";
```

And add that in to return

```
<FormItem label="Rate">
    {getFieldDecorator('ORSalesAndPurchaseSalesPrice', {
        initialValue: "",                   
    })(
        <Input placeholder={rate}/>
    )}
</FormItem>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please remove the quotes as, placeholder will then take the value of `{rate}` string.

Comment: @Easwar correct! Having this multiple time with React! hope not to repeat it ;)

Comment: I tried this code. But showing the "%" symbol always

Comment: @JaneFred changed `value.ItemTpeId==1` to `value.ItemTpeId===1` for strict checking.

Comment: Yes it worked 
Can you tell me the validation for this FormItem so that only numbers and a decimal point is needed.

Comment: @JaneFred Match the value with this regex :  /^[+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?$/

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps. Add regex as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023845/regex-in-javascript-for-validating-decimal-numbers

Comment: % symbol
Decimal Point
0-9

Comment: @Easwar I am using  `e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');` this syntax .Could you please help how to include decimal and percentage symbol in this