# Decimal Format Validation

Tags: javascript

I want to enforce a validation in my submission form where the user should input this format x.xxx in my GPA field. If the format is not followed the form will not be submitted.

Ex:

1.123 - valid
1.11 - invalid
123 - invalid

Please help, I've spent hours looking for a solution to no avail.

Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023845/regex-in-javascript-for-validating-decimal-numbers/36485704

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regexp for Decimal Format( x.xxx) Validation. use `/^\d+\.\d{3}$/` for matches at first Decimal then point then exactly 3 digits.

```js
var regexp = /^\d+\.\d{3}$/;

// returns true
console.log(regexp.test('1.123'));

// returns false
console.log(regexp.test('1.11'));
 // returns false
console.log(regexp.test('123'));
```

Implementation

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["GPA"].value;
  var regexp = /^\d+\.\d{3}$/;
  if (!regexp.test(x)) {
    alert("GPA will x.xxx format");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
GPA: <input type="text" name="GPA">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, 

I'm sorry for being ignorant, but can you help me righ an if statement that will prompt an error message if console.log(regexp.test('1.123')); will return false?

I reviewed in the developer tools in my and the code is returning the correct value, I just don't know how to implement this.

I don't even know how to add a code snippet in this comment.

Comment: @RJofthenoobs which validation library using for validation or using row?

Comment: I'm just using a simple JS code, here is my sample code https://prnt.sc/mwgmqi

Comment: @RJofthenoobs Added Implement code. Please check. If any problem please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mohammad, your sample code work perfectly. Really appreciate your help.

Have a nice day!

Comment: @RJofthenoobs you are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to string.Use substring to get the length of the substring after the decimal and the end of the string. If it is 3 return true else false

```js
var a=123.233;
String(a).substr(String(a).indexOf('.')+1,String(a).length-1).length==3?console.log(true):console.log(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function. It also checks, if the strings before and after the decimal point are valid numbers.

```js
function validate(num) {
  let numS = num.split('.');
  return numS.length==2 && numS[0].length==1 && numS[1].length==3 && !isNaN(numS[0]) && !isNaN(numS[1])
}

console.log(validate('1.1'))
console.log(validate('1.12'))
console.log(validate('1.123'))
console.log(validate('1,123'))
```