# How to write regex for accepting a number or a decimal with only one point?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angular, validation

I have an input which should take if it is an integer

12 --> Accept

or

12.3 -->Accept

12.33 --> do not accept

So far i tried this but this didnt work.Can anyone please help.Thanks.

```
\\d+([.]\\d{2})?
```

Comment: Please show the code, how/where you are using the regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Decimal Place Restriction With RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468655/javascript-decimal-place-restriction-with-regex)

Comment: `\d+(?:\.\d)?`?

Comment: Have you set `type="text"`? If you have `type="number"`, regex validation does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
 /^[1-9]\d*(\.[0-9]?)?$/
```

Comment: @Nishal,its not working accepting any number of decimals

Answer (score 0):

Without more info it's hard to give a better solution than

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d)?$/
```

It matches any number of integer digits, optionally followed by a decimal point and **one** digit.

The first problem with your attempt is that you match 2 (`{2}`) digits after the decimal point.
The second problem is the same as with Nisals solution, it matches the number with the given number of decimals, but it doesn't check that the number terminates after that. Adding start and end anchors (`^` and `$`) fixes that.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/seI2MO/1).